Why GBX is the abbreviation of Great British Pence?
Why  GBX is the abbreviation of Great British Pence ?No X in Great British Pence!

I’m voting to close this question because the abbreviation is an arbitrary international convention, not part of the English language.

It's just a convention, and, according to Wikipedia, not an a official one. There is a convention (ISO 4217), which covers international finance and currency codes for whole currency units, such as GBP, USD, etc.
In international trading (metals, stocks, energy, etc) it may be inconvenient to use decimal fractions like USD 3.41 so an unofficial (but widely used) non-ISO convention is that when they are mutliplied by 100 to eliminate the decimal point (e.g. USX 341), the symbol often used is an X, e.g. GBX, USX, CAX, EUX. So GBP 5.99 is shown as GBX 599.
That is not the only convention, and you may see USc GBp, EUc, and so on. Why the X arose is a matter for speculation.
